# Konsole removing leading whitespace when copy pasting?

Tags: konsole

I don't know if I changed something, or because a newer version changed behavior, but whenever I copy something that has indentation, the resulting text in my clipboard has its indentation removed (text on ever new line starts at column 0).

This is extremely annoying, as I regularly copy/paste from things like YaML and docker compose files and need to re-do the indentation.

Can't find an option that seems related to this. Anyone any ideas/tips?

I'm running Manjaro 6.3 with KDE Plasma 5.27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been annoyed by this exact same issue, this seems to be something that was introduced recently.  I clicked around in the settings and found a solution.  In the top menu bar, go to:

```
Settings
    => Edit Current Profile
    => Mouse - Ensure 'Text interaction' tab is selected
    => Uncheck 'Trim leading spaces'
    => OK
```

Your leading spaces should be preserved now.